# What methods does the OtherMethods property refer to on properties and events in the Mono.Cecil object model?

Tags: mono.cecil

Namely:

- `Mono.Cecil.PropertyDefinition.OtherMethods`
- `Mono.Cecil.EventDefinition.OtherMethods`

These are neither Get/Set not Add/Remove methods. So what are they?